# add objects to the dictionary using for loop

Tags: iphone, ios, for-loop, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

in my program i want to add 20 objects to dictionary using for loop so i did

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;

    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"];
    NSLog(@"%i",[latestLoans count]);

parsedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


for (int i=0; i<[latestLoans count]; i++) {


    //get latest loan
    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:i];

    //fetch the data
    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

    [parsedDict setObject:fundedAmount forKey:@"funded_amount"];
    [parsedDict setObject:loanAmount forKey:@"loan_amount"];
    [parsedDict setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [parsedDict setObject:country forKey:@"location"];
        }
nslog(@"%@",parsedDict);
```

but when i log it out of the loop i am getting only the last added values..not all the values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array to store the records...

```
  NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.responseData = nil;

        NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"];
        NSLog(@"%i",[latestLoans count]);


     NSMutableArray someArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<[latestLoans count]; i++) {

    parsedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        //get latest loan
        NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:i];

        //fetch the data
        NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
        NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
        float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

        NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

        [parsedDict setObject:fundedAmount forKey:@"funded_amount"];
        [parsedDict setObject:loanAmount forKey:@"loan_amount"];
        [parsedDict setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
        [parsedDict setObject:country forKey:@"location"];
        [someArray addObject:parsedDict];
            }
    NSLog(@"%@",parsedDict);

//Read from Array


for(NSDictionary *tempDict in someArray) 
{
   //use [tempDict objectForKey:@"keyName"] to get values from each dictionary
}
```

Comment: how can i retrieve the object for key . if i use the array to store the dictionaries

Comment: for(NSDictionary *tempDict in someArray)
{
do stuff
}

Comment: NSLog the latestLoans array and see

Comment: ya it contains all the 20 different datas

Comment: change for (int i=0; i<[latestLoans count]; i++) to for(NSDictionary* loan in someArray) and remove the line   NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:i];

Answer (score 4):

If you add 2 values with the same key only the last one will be shown as the other ones are all overwriten. You might want to (even tho it's not that pretty) add a dictionary for each loop to an array/dictionary.

Comment: if i add dictionary to another dictionary then how to retrive the data. can u please give me a sample code to do that..

Comment: @krishna I think you need to go and read the documentation for NSDictionary - understand what it does rather than just trying to get code snippets to stick together.

Comment: the example of Akash Malhotra is what i said in this answer.